# Enveloping Algebra equal to algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital associative ring, $A$ be an associative $R$-algebra of finite dimension, and $A^e$ its enveloping algebra.

What are the requirements on $A$, so that $A^e \cong A$ *(as $R$-algebras)*?

Comment: You want conditions on $A$ that imply $A^e\cong A$? That's a rather weird question... This happens rarely, really —and mostly, I guess, for silly reasons (A is an infinite tensor product power of some algebra, like the polynomial ring on infinitely many variables, or something like that)

Comment: Hmmm... can you give me a source for that?

Comment: Why what? ${}{}$

Comment: oh, sorry I did n't see the entire post before I commented :/
Umm I forgot to specify I need A to be finite dimensional.

Comment: If $A$ is finite dimensional over a field (and $R$ is the field...), then you **never** (except when $A=R$) have $A^e\cong A$, simply because the two algebras have different finite dimension. If $R$ is not a field, then you should tell us what you mean by dimension of $A$. (Your $R$ should at least be commutative and central in $A$, if you want $A^e$ to be an algebra)